# Elasticsearch phrase prefix query on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, match, field

I'm new to ES and I'm trying to build a query that would use phrase_prefix for multiple fields so I dont have to search more than once.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
{ 
    "query" : { 
        "text" : { 
            "first_name" : { 
                "query" : "Gustavo", 
                "type" : "phrase_prefix" 
            }
        } 
    }
}'
```

Does anybody knows how to search for more than one field, say "last_name" ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [text query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/text-query/) that you are using has been deprecated (effectively renamed) a while ago in favour of the [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/). The match query supports a single field, but you can use the [multi_match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) which supports the very same options and allows to search on multiple fields. Here is an example that should be helpful to you:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "fields" : ["title", "subtitle"],
            "query" : "trying out ela",
            "type" : "phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}
```

You can achieve the same using the Java API like this:

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("trying out ela", "title", "subtitle")
    .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);
```

Comment: awesome! thank you very much! by the way, do you know by any chance how to accomplish this in Java? I can't find in the docs.. http://rajish.github.io/api/elasticsearch/0.20.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.html#multiMatchQuery(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String...)

Comment: Thanks,w orks nicely! For me, it made sense to use/add `"fields" : [ "*" ], "lenient" : true` so that **all** fields are searched, and _text_ entry does not cause Exceptions when a numeric field is (implicitly) included in the field list.

Comment: The above didn't give me phrase prefix I don't think

Comment: @mgaert thanks, your suggestion worked. Maybe it should be on its own anwser :)