# Mapping + Query in Elastic Search

Tags: json, rest, lucene, elasticsearch

**Context**

Essentially what I have is a large dataset of names, split into pty_firstname and pty_surname. I index this data into ElasticSearch from an Informix DB, this all works fine. However what I am failing to achieve is a logical mapping for this table structure, and a query to benefit from the mapping. Where I seem to be having issues is that the names are actually split into two columns, making to me, the query a bit more tricky to return a sound result set.

If anyone could give me some help, in order for me to return a result set with the closest if not exact matches at the top, and as we progress through the result set the less similar the results become.

**Mapping**

I tried to get some inspiration for my mapping and query here, with some alterations however I can't seem to get the results I need/want - http://goo.gl/hm9ISL

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "user":{
         "properties":{
            "pty_forename":{
               "type":"multi_field",
               "fields":{
                  "name":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"analyzed"
                  },
                  "exact":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            },
            "pty_surname":{
               "type":"multi_field",
               "fields":{
                  "name":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"analyzed"
                  },
                  "exact":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "index":"not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            },
            "pty_minute_ref":{
               "type":"integer",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_deed_code":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_name_prefix":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_name_suffix":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_address":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_desig_suffix":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_mc_ind":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_of_ind":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_or_ind":{
               "type":"integer",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_date_entered":{
               "type":"basic_date",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_data":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "pty_type":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"Nathan Smith",
                  "fields":[
                     "pty_forename",
                     "pty_surname"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "should":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "pty_forename.exact":{
                     "value":"Nathan Smith",
                     "boost":15
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "prefix":{
                  "pty_forename.exact":{
                     "value":"Nathan Smith",
                     "boost":10
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "pty_forename":{
                     "query":"Nathan Smith",
                     "slop":0,
                     "boost":5
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Conclusion**

The result set that I am getting back isn't querying across both fields i.e. pty_forename AND pty_surname, and is returning people with a surname of Nathan etc,. Any help would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE - Link to Gist**

[Link to Gist](https://gist.github.com/NSmeef/6239957)

Comment: What do you mean by the result set "isn't querying across both result sets"? Could you perhaps make a gist?

Comment: @ramseykhalaf just made an edit to that last paragraph, hope that makes a little more sense. Making a gist now, will update in a second. Thanks.

Comment: It works, but there are probably 30 other different ways of doing it. Of which I'm interested in all.

Comment: do the answers work for you? If so please accept one to reward the answerer! (And so more people don't spend time typing an answer to something that's been solved.)

Comment: Or if they don't work could you comment on why, to help other answerers...

Comment: @ramseykhalaf I'm well aware of how SO works, I will accept.

Comment: I didn't mean to stop discussion, I just read your Q and the A's and was wondering how I could help. If you were to say why a question didn't work exactly it would help alot (those poor alots never get any help)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
"bool" : {
    "should" : {
        "match" : { "pty_forename" : "nathan" }
    },
    "should" : {
        "match" : { "pty_surname" : "smith" }
    }
}
```

That is, all result with `pty_forename` = "nathan" OR `pty_surname` = "smith" (higher score for both).

Comment: This works, and returns a decent set of results, thanks. The annoying thing is, I can't seem to concatenate the two should's and matches to gether, the reason I want to do that I'm build a web front-end and parsing this to a string causes a duplicate key problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NSmeef - Sorry for the delay on responding, here.  I would just duplicate the data in a name field (say `pty_name`), which concatenates any name components together (should be indexed and unstored).  A loosely formatted, user-entered name string could search against that single field using a [`query_string` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/), or similar.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the StackOverflow example you linked and in [the elasticsearch Multifield documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type/), under the heading "accessing fields", **the first field listed under "fields" in a multi_field type should have the same name as the field itself**. So, in the SO and documentation examples, "name" is the first name given under "fields" because "name" is the name of the multi_type field. In your example, your mapping should be

   ```
       "pty_forename":{
          "type":"multi_field",
          "fields":{
             "pty_forename":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"analyzed"
             },
             "exact":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
             }
          }
       },
       "pty_surname":{
          "type":"multi_field",
          "fields":{
             "pty_surname":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"analyzed"
             },
             "exact":{
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
             }
          }
       },
   ```

   As your mapping is now, your "bool" "must" query *might* not be doing anything, since none of your multi_field "fields" are currently named "pty_forename" or "pty_surname". I say *might* because I don't know whether Elasticsearch still saves a multi_field under its name, even if you don't use that name in the "fields" section.
2. Your "bool" "should" query needs to search for both "pty_forename" and "pty_surname", as 
   femtoRgon suggests, maybe like this:

   ```
         "multi_match" : {
               "fields" : ["pty_forename.exact", "pty_surname.exact"],
               "value" : "Nathan Smith",
               "type" : "term"
         },
        "multi_match" : {
               "fields" : ["pty_forename.exact", "pty_surname.exact"],
               "value" : "Nathan Smith",
               "type" : "prefix"
         },
         "multi_match" : {
               "fields" : ["pty_forename.exact", "pty_surname.exact"],
               "query" : "Nathan Smith",
               "slop":0,
               "boost":5,
               "type" : "match_phrase"
         }
   ```

I looked at javanna's answer here [Elasticsearch phrase prefix query on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562964/elasticsearch-phrase-prefix-query-on-multiple-fields).