# ElasticSearch Match Multiple Prefix Terms

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am trying to give ElasticSearch a query with multiple terms and then be given matching documents where the terms specified are anywhere in the target field. The terms may be full words or word prefixes.

**Example document**:

{
"msg": "hello I am a text message"
}

**Example query string**:

"hello message"

The words "hello" and "message" appear in the text so I want the document returned. The same query should also return the document if the query string is:

"hel mes"

What is the most performant way to query ElasticSearch to achieve this goal?

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562964/elasticsearch-phrase-prefix-query-on-multiple-fields